# Regex for "anything between" 2 patterns

Tags: node.js, regex

I have a string with multiple URLs and other content in it.

I have URLs in following format:

`http://www.example.com/bla1/bla2/thumb_my-file-name(2).JPG`

The part till `http://www.example.com/bla1/bla2/thumb_` is fixed.

However, I dont know what will be: `my-file-name(2)`. I know it will be ending with `.JPG`

So far, I'm using the following regex to detect them:

`/http:\/\/www.example.com\/bla1\/bla2\/thumb_/g`

and I have also used `\.JPG` to detect the end.

But how do I capture the middle part as well?
How do I catch this whole URL?

Comment: please post the code. Is this express server?

Comment: I'm sending a request from nodejs. Need to find the URLs in the received response. Thats it.

Comment: I dont understand the downvotes. I've explained everything in the description, posted example and my existing expression. Couldn't find a better title.

Comment: well you did not post enough code and forced others that want to help you to guess what you mean and what stack you do have behind the question etc. This is annoying when you are on the answerer's side => you get downvotes (I did not make any, just trying to explain why I would do that)

Comment: What else is there to post? I posted my input, the regex that I'm using on it, and the output I need! Its just `input.exec(regEx)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex pattern:

```
http://www.example.com/bla1/bla2/thumb_(.*?)\.JPG
```

**Code:**

```js
var url = "http://www.example.com/bla1/bla2/thumb_my-file-name(2).JPG";
var myRegexp = /http:\/\/www.example.com\/bla1\/bla2\/thumb_(.*?)\.JPG/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(url);
console.log(match[1]); // my-file-name(2)
```

Comment: Hah! works! I had tried `\[(.*?)\]` :D

Comment: yes, sorry for the delay in marking it as answer. It didnt let me do immediately, and wasn't online for last few days. I dont understand the downvotes though

Comment: I also don't understand the downvotes, it seems overly harsh to me.

Comment: I posted my input, the regex that I'm using on it, and the output I need! What matters is the expression, and not `input.exec(regEx)`. Wish they made people specify reason for downvote so the OP can atleast know what needs to be refined. :(

Comment: @DushyantBangal I upvoted your question and honestly don't think it's an exact duplicate.  But I don't have a gold medal in regex so I cannot reopen it.